# SSIS Script Task: ADO.NET connection manager does not use login parameters

Tags: ssis

I have a parametrized ADO.NET connection manager in a Script Task that is defined with Windows authentication at design but has 4 parameters defined: ServerName, InitialCatalog, LoginName and Password. When it runs, it tries using my Domain Login to connect to the server rather than the LoginName defined in the parameters. The OleDB connection manager in the same script, defined with the same parameters, works fine. The OleDB cm is also using Windows Auth at design.

Comment: What's the `Integrated Security` setting?

Comment: I'm not using the ConnectionString parameter. It should not be setting Integrated Security as long as the UserName and Password are defined.